# Get an integer and convert it to a date - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to extract the date from a members CPR numbers in my Database, its stored as an integer. (CPR is Danish social security number and the first 6 characters are your date of birth)

Here is my SQL statement however it doesn't quite work. The SELECT LEFT bit works its just the STR_TO_DATE which returns an error.

```
SELECT LEFT(cpr, 6) AS @iCPR FROM members
STR_TO_DATE(iCPR,'p%m%Y')
```

Comment: Please show sample data AND the error message.

Comment: You can't just run STR_TO_DATE(iCPR,'%d%m%Y') even if you get the format right. The database doesn't know what to do with that information. You have to select it.

I'm also not sure the first line of your code would run correctly without the str_to_date() function. Have you tried running that first?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a mistake in your STR_TO_DATE format. Try changing it to '%d%m%Y'.

See here for the list of valid specifiers for that function:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format